# Assign values in pandas column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, replace, merge

I have two dataframes like the ones that are shown below:

A

```
Timestamp C1 C2 C3
1 0 0 0 
2 0 0 0
3 0 0 0
4 0 0 0
5 0 0 0
6 0 0 0
7 0 0 0
```

and
B

```
Timestamp C1 C2 C3
2 0 0 0
3 v1 v2 v3
4 v4 v5 v6
7 0 0 0
```

I want to merge the two datasets and replace the zeros in A with the values in B based on the Timestamp column and have a new A dataframe like the one shown below:

```
Timestamp C1 C2 C3
1 0 0 0 
2 0 0 0
3 v1 v2 v3
4 v4 v5 v6
5 0 0 0
6 0 0 0
7 0 0 0
```

Comment: Use `pd.merge()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for replace `0` to `NaN`s with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
#convert columns to indices if necessary
#A = A.set_index('Timestamp')
#B = B.set_index('Timestamp')

df = B.mask(B == 0).combine_first(A)
#alternative
#df = B.replace({0:np.nan}).combine_first(A)
print (df)
           C1  C2  C3
Timestamp            
1           0   0   0
2           0   0   0
3          v1  v2  v3
4          v4  v5  v6
5           0   0   0
6           0   0   0
7           0   0   0
```